# valid_referers nginx http and https

Tags: linux, shell, nginx

I've a mp4 download site. Some websites are using my site's feed, that's why I am loosing my limited Bandwidth.

I've used the following code to restrict access to my mp4 files from third-party referers.

```
    location ~* .*\.mp4 {
    valid_referers sitexxx.com *.sitexxx.com;
            if ($invalid_referer) {
            return   403;
    }
        mp4;
    }
```

This works well for HTTP sites (e.g. http://www.example.com), but doesn't work at all with HTTPS sites (e.g. https://example.blogspot.com). Why is that and how can I block those?

Answer (score 0):

1: I guess it doesn't specify server port. you can try it.
references:http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html#valid_referers

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
     # error_log /var/log/nginx/vhost-error_log warn;
      listen 11.111.1:80;
      server_name xxxx.com www.xxxx.com;
      log_not_found off;
      root /home/xxxx/public_html;
```

location / {

```
           # enable MP4 streaming
     location ~* .*\.mp4 {
    valid_referers ~xxxx ~www.xxxx.com;
            if ($invalid_referer) {
            return   403;
    }
        mp4;
    }

    }
```

}

my code is this, I tried to put the ~ but also did not work, it seems that the problem is aimed at identifying the refer in the logs, the requests are not listed reference.